# jQuery - How to add row to table automatically only if all previous fields are filled

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function that used to add new row to html table on button click. I am trying to change this behavior and happen only if all fields of the table are filled but currently is populating rows infinitely. How to overcome this? Sorry I'm not an expert..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 1;
  $("form").on('change', function() {
    var row_added = false;
    $('#invoice_form textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        row_added = true;
      }
    });
    if (row_added) {
      count++;
      $('#total_item').val(count);
      var html_code = '';
      html_code += '<tr id="row_id_' + count + '">';
      html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">' + count + '</span></td>';
      html_code += '<td><span class="pull-left"><a href="#addnew" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>+</a></span></td>';
      html_code += '<td><textarea cols="200" rows="20" name="item_name[]" id="item_name' + count + '" class="form-control"></textarea></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="number" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity' + count + '" data-srno="' + count + '" class="form-control" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="number" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price' + count + '" data-srno="' + count + '" class="form-control" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><input type="number" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount' + count + '" data-srno="' + count + '" readonly class="form-control" /></td>';
      html_code += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_row" id="' + count + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row">X</button></td>';
      html_code += '</tr>';
      $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="sr_no">1</span></td>
    <td><span class="pull-left"><a href="#addnew" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>+</a>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td><textarea cols="200" rows="20" name="item_name[]" id="item_name1" class="form-control" autofocus></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity1" data-srno="1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="1" step="any" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price1" data-srno="1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="1" step="any" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control" /></td>
    <th/>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi sorry for not adding the minimal reproducible example. I think now it should be ok

Comment: 1) Your code has no `<form>`, so the handler doesn't match anything and your code never runs.  2) Your code has no element with id `invoice_form`, so `$('#invoice_form textarea')` will not match anything, and `row_added` will never change. 3) Your title says "*... all previous fields are filled ...*", but the code is only checking the `textarea`? Do you want to check all `input`s too?  In either case, do you want to check only the last one, or every row?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. 
The form is not included here because is very big. I just added the piece of code we care.
Invoice_form is the name of the form including this code.
As for the check I would like to check all the fields everytime because If the previous rows are edited to empty then it should not add a new row. E.g. Row_1 is filed then row_2 is added. If row_1 edited to empty and row_2 is filled, it should not add a new line